# SessionID was changed when signle sign on (SSO) with Azure Active Directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, single-sign-on

My Asp.Net Application integrated SSO with Azure Active Directory.

At the login screen, user selects some fields > we store them to Session > user click on the Login via 
AzureAD button > user was redirected to Microsoft Login page > Microfsoft redirect user back to my application after authenticated, Session values lost here because the SessionID was changed.

Please help me to retain these Session values?

Comment: Hi Rango, may I know if you have some code to do cross domain access in your application ? (or if your login url and redirect url are two sub domains ?)

Comment: Hi Hury Shen, I test on localhost. Login url is https://localhost:44302/login.aspx and redirect url is https://localhost:44302/default.aspx. I don't have any code to do cross domain.

Comment: Doesn't sound like an issue with Azure AD to me. It could be related to the recent changes to cookies SameSite stuff. So by default cookies are set SameSite=Lax unless otherwise defined. This will prevent them from being sent in certain situations. You'll want to at least check your session cookie configuration.

Comment: Hi @Rango, my opinion is similar to juunas. It seems the issue is related to cookies because sessionId stored in cookies. So I asked you if the code includes cross domain or sub domains which will affect the cookies to be sent. But it seems your project doesn't have the code. So I'm not sure what cause this issue, maybe you need to review the code in detail to check if the cookie was prevented.